# Insert text token from one line into a specific position on the next line

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I have a file with text data that I need to convert into SQL statements.

```
@Parse ABC
// This is a comment

//-----

"f2"
f4-1
$f5f5f5f5 0000
f4-2
$f5f5f5f5 0001
$f5f5f5f5 0002
f4-3
$f5f5f5f5 0003
$f5f5f5f5 0004
f4-4
$f5f5f5f5 0005
$f5f5f5f5 0006
f4-5
$f5f5f5f5 0007
$f5f5f5f5 0008
$f5f5f5f5 0009
$f5f5f5f5 0010
$f5f5f5f5 0011
$f5f5f5f5 0012

//========

"This is f2 but is different from the previous f2"
f4-6
$f5f5f5f5 0013
f4-7
$f5f5f5f5 0014
$f5f5f5f5 0015
f4-8
$f5f5f5f5 0016
$f5f5f5f5 0017
f4-9
$f5f5f5f5 0018
$f5f5f5f5 0019
f4-10
$f5f5f5f5 0020
$f5f5f5f5 0021
$f5f5f5f5 0022
$f5f5f5f5 0023
$f5f5f5f5 0024
$f5f5f5f5 0025

//========
```

Originally the file looked like the above.

I would like this file to look like this

```
INSERT INTO `` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`) VALUES (NULL, "f2-1", "", "f4-1", "$f5f5f5f5 0000");
INSERT INTO `` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`) VALUES (NULL, "f2-1", "", "f4-2", "$f5f5f5f5 0001<TAB>$f5f5f5f5 0002");
INSERT INTO `` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`) VALUES (NULL, "f2-1", "", "f4-3", "$f5f5f5f5 0003<TAB>$f5f5f5f5 0004");
INSERT INTO `` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`) VALUES (NULL, "f2-1", "", "f4-4", "$f5f5f5f5 0005<TAB>$f5f5f5f5 0006");
INSERT INTO `` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`) VALUES (NULL, "f2-1", "", "f4-5", "$f5f5f5f5 0007<TAB>$f5f5f5f5 0008<TAB>$f5f5f5f5 0009<TAB>$f5f5f5f5 0010<TAB>$f5f5f5f5 0011<TAB>$f5f5f5f5 0012");
INSERT INTO `` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`) VALUES (NULL, "This is f2-2 but is different from the previous f2-1", "", "f4-6", "$f5f5f5f5 0013");
INSERT INTO `` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`) VALUES (NULL, "This is f2-2 but is different from the previous f2-1", "", "f4-7", "$f5f5f5f5 0014<TAB>$f5f5f5f5 0015");
INSERT INTO `` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`) VALUES (NULL, "This is f2-2 but is different from the previous f2-1", "", "f4-8", "$f5f5f5f5 0016<TAB>$f5f5f5f5 0017");
INSERT INTO `` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`) VALUES (NULL, "This is f2-2 but is different from the previous f2-1", "", "f4-9", "$f5f5f5f5 0018<TAB>$f5f5f5f5 0019");
INSERT INTO `` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`) VALUES (NULL, "This is f2-2 but is different from the previous f2-1", "", "f4-10", "$f5f5f5f5 0020<TAB>$f5f5f5f5 0021<TAB>$f5f5f5f5 0022<TAB>$f5f5f5f5 0023<TAB>$f5f5f5f5 0024<TAB>$f5f5f5f5 0025");
```

I used the command below to change the original file into the output as it currently now stands at, all the files used in the command below have dos line endings.

```
sed -e 's/[[:space:]]$//' -e 's/^[[:alnum:]*()].*/INSERT INTO `` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`) VALUES (NULL, "", "", "&", "");/' /path/to/files/* > '/path/to/file.sql';
```

The data as it currently stands in 'file.sql' is as follows:

```
@Parse ABC
// This is a comment

//-----

"f2"
INSERT INTO `` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`) VALUES (NULL, "", "", "f4-1", "");
$f5f5f5f5 0000
INSERT INTO `` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`) VALUES (NULL, "", "", "f4-2", "");
$f5f5f5f5 0001
$f5f5f5f5 0002
INSERT INTO `` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`) VALUES (NULL, "", "", "f4-3", "");
$f5f5f5f5 0003
$f5f5f5f5 0004
INSERT INTO `` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`) VALUES (NULL, "", "", "f4-4", "");
$f5f5f5f5 0005
$f5f5f5f5 0006
INSERT INTO `` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`) VALUES (NULL, "", "", "f4-5", "");
$f5f5f5f5 0007
$f5f5f5f5 0008
$f5f5f5f5 0009
$f5f5f5f5 0010
$f5f5f5f5 0011
$f5f5f5f5 0012

//========

"This is f2 but is different from the previous f2"
INSERT INTO `` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`) VALUES (NULL, "", "", "f4-6", "");
$f5f5f5f5 0013
INSERT INTO `` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`) VALUES (NULL, "", "", "f4-7", "");
$f5f5f5f5 0014
$f5f5f5f5 0015
INSERT INTO `` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`) VALUES (NULL, "", "", "f4-8", "");
$f5f5f5f5 0016
$f5f5f5f5 0017
INSERT INTO `` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`) VALUES (NULL, "", "", "f4-9", "");
$f5f5f5f5 0018
$f5f5f5f5 0019
INSERT INTO `` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`) VALUES (NULL, "", "", "f4-10", "");
$f5f5f5f5 0020
$f5f5f5f5 0021
$f5f5f5f5 0022
$f5f5f5f5 0023
$f5f5f5f5 0024
$f5f5f5f5 0025

//========
```

I'm wanting to change the data above into the following:

```
INSERT INTO `` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`) VALUES (NULL, "", "", "f4-1", "");
INSERT INTO `` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`) VALUES (NULL, "", "", "f4-2", "$f5f5f5f5 0000");
```

The file that contains the data has dos line endings.

```
sed -r "s/\", \"\"\);\r\n(.*)\r\nINSERT INTO/\", \"\1\");\r\nINSERT INTO/" /path/to/file.sql;
```

The above command does run without errors, but the output from the command is the same as the input.

I did initially try to get `sed -e` to work, but that gave me errors I couldn't fix, these were mostly escaping character issues that `sed -r` fixed.

I have just tried to only replace the line endings such as replace `\r\n` with `----`. But they didn't get replaced, so I think that's where my problem lies.

So I have since discovered `sed` works on lines, I didn't realise that, so this doesn't necessarily have to be done in sed, although I am at a loss as to what I would use instead, if someone would like to suggest something to use I am happy to have a go myself and post again if I have issues.

Comment: Do the line endings need to be preserved as DOS-style? Does it have to be `sed`, or are other standard tools an option? Are all (apart from the first) `INSERT` lines preceded by a value to fill into the 5th argument of the `VALUES` list of the next line?

Comment: Note that if you use `'` for your sed expression, you don't need to escape the `"`. And if you _don't_ use `-r`, you also don't need to escape the `)` or `(`. Your `sed` command is equivalent to this one: `sed  's/", "");\r\n\(.*\)\r\nINSERT INTO/", "\1");\r\nINSERT INTO/' file`. That said, `sed` works on _lines_. There are trickes for multi-line things, but you can't just match across a `\n` like that. Does this _need_ to be done in sed?

Comment: @AdminBee Sorry I missed part of your comment, no the line endings don't need to be preserved I could also just do a unix2dos command later, also yes lines are preceded by a value to fill into the 5th argument.

Comment: Your attempt seems to imply that you insert everything between two INSERT lines into the fifth field, including the index number `0001` and perhaps even multiple lines if there is more than one line between two INSERT lines, but your output says something different. `sed` has the `N;P;D` pattern to process multiple lines together, but I need to understand the goal. GNU `sed` also has the `-z` option to process the whole file at once, but you need to change your script or the `.*` will eat up everything between the first and the last.

Answer (score 2):

**Note** The example input/desired output was changed drastically since this answer was posted, so it will likely not solve the question as it stands now.

The following solution assumes that

- the value to be inserted is the only string token on the line
- the place where the value is to be inserted is the `"");` pattern

Under these circumstances, the following `awk` program should work:

```
awk 'index($0,"INSERT")==1 && buf {sub(/"");/, "\"" buf "\");"); buf=""}
NF==1{buf=$1;next} 1' input.txt
```

It works as follows:

- If the line starts with `INSERT`, and a buffer variable `buf` is filled, it will substitute the `"");` pattern with `"`, followed by the content of `buf` , followed by `");`. The `buf` variable is then cleared.
- If there is only one field on the line, it is assumed that this is a line containing the value to fill in the next line, and this is then placed into the `buf` variable (but otherwise processing immediately skips to the next line).
- The seemingly stray `1` outside of the rule block `{ ... }` instructs `awk` to print the current line, including all modifications made.

If there are several "value" lines before an `INSERT` line, it will take the content of the last such "value" line. Empty lines are ignored (but will still appear in the output). Lines with more than one "word" that don't start with `INSERT` will also be printed unchanged.

Note that `awk` by default doesn't perform in-place editing of the file (just as `sed`), so you need to redirect the output into a file and overwrite the original input later, or (if you have a fairly new GNU Awk), use the `-i inplace` extension to perform inplace-editing.

It is advisable to run the original file through `dos2unix` to replace the DOS line-endings with Unix-style before processing. You can run  `unix2dos` afterwards if the DOS line-endings are needed in the modified file.

Comment: Does this only work with 1 file as the input, or can I feed it a directory with a bunch of files in it? just I have a bunch of files that I am concatenating into a single file, but I may decide that I would like to replace the strings in the original files. so it would be handy if this worked for both cases.

Comment: You can pass multiple files as operands. The only thing to keep in mind is that in its current form, the program will not clear a "leftover" `buf` at end-of-file, so if a file ends with a "value" line, but the next file doesn't start with a "value" line, the first `INSERT` line of that file will be filled in with the "unused" value of the previous file.

Comment: if there is one or more lines between the two insert statements will this still work?

Comment: Yes, but it will use the "value" from the last non-empty line to fill into a `INSERT` line, discarding previously read "value" lines (if any). If you have special requirements, please be sure to post an input example that includes "edge"-cases. Apart from that, you could just try the command to see if it works. As stated, in the form posted it is "non-destructive".

Comment: I updated my question with a better example of the file, I understand it will miss some parts, but that's fine as there won't be many I could potentially fix these manually or run over the file again and fix the ones missed with other code.

Also I couldn't get your answer to work on the example data I posted above, it does make some changes, but the changes it makes are incorrect.

Comment: @AeroMaxx I'm confused. The example input looks like it contains 2x the same `"f2"` section, is this indended? Also, what would the complete desired output look like?

Comment: Yes and no, the formatting is how it appears in the example above, but the values would be different for all the f2, f3, f4, f5 there would be no duplicates. The data is just to show the formatting, and which parts of the file go into which fields in the sql.

Comment: I have since edited my question, hopefully this will have cleared somethings up.

Answer (score 0):

To make `sed` work on pairs of lines, you use the `N;P;D` pattern: Append the `N`ext line to the buffer, `P`rint only the first line in the buffer and `D`elete the first line to continue the script with the second line still in the buffer.

In your case this would lead to

```
sed 'N;s/", "");\r\n\($[^ ]*\).*/", "\1");/;P;D' /path/to/file
```

Now I'm not sure what you want to do if there are additional lines. Maybe just get rid of them:

```
sed '/^$/d;N;s/", "");\r\n\($[^ ]*\).*/", "\1");/;P;D' /path/to/file
```

Comment: I have since edited my question, hopefully this will have cleared somethings up.